# Reading directories and files as root on Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, root

I'm writing an App to backup data. Some data can just be read with a rooted phone. This is not a problem, of course, but I don't know how I can read a complete directory with all subdirectories and files...

I know, that I have to create a Process with "su", but I don't want to create a Process, read the directory with "ls", read the files with "cat" and then recursive for all directories, every time creating a new process...

How can I solve my problem in Java?

Thanks a lot
Luca